# Prove $\sum_{k\geq1} \frac{\sin(ka)}{ka}\cos(kx)$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

Assume $a\in ]0,\pi[$. How do I prove $\sum_{k\geq1} \dfrac{\sin(ka)}{ka}\cos(kx)$ is convergent for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?
I tried writing $\sin(ka)=\dfrac{e^{ika}-e^{-ika}}{2i}$ and $\cos(kx)=\dfrac{e^{ikz}+e^{-ikz}}{2}$ but I did not get far.

Comment: Try Dirichlet's test

Answer (score 1):

We use the following two formulas for finite sums of sines and cosines:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \cos kx=\frac{\sin\frac{nx}2}{\sin\frac x2}\cdot\cos\left(\frac{n+1}2x\right)\;,\;\;\sum_{k=1}^n \sin kx=\frac{\sin\frac{nx}2}{\sin\frac x2}\cdot\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2x\right)$$

and now we can use Dirichlet's Test (=D.T.):

First, if $\;x=2m\pi\;,\;\;m\in\Bbb Z\;$, then $\;\cos(kx)=\cos(2mk\pi)=1\;$, so the series becomes

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin ka}{ka}$$

and this series converges since $\;\left\{a_k\right\}=\left\{\frac1{ka}\right\}\;$ is monotnically descending sequence to zero, and for all $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ :

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n \sin ka\right|=\left|\frac{\sin\frac{na}2}{\sin\frac a2}\cdot\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2a\right)\right|\le\frac1{\left|\sin\frac a2\right|}\;$$

and the rightmost expression is well defined since $\;0<a<\pi\;$ and it is a finite number, so by D.T the series converges.

If $\;x\neq2m\pi\;,\;\;m\in\Bbb Z\;$, you now use a very similar argument as the above one to deduce the given series once again converges by D.T.

Comment: I wish the OP knew what did you do by this illustrated answer! I doubt about that.